# Is there a way to disable right click menu in cmd?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

I'm writing a mouse input to console game engine, but context menu pops up every time I press right mouse button and messes my events.

Input in my program is processed by a child window, attached to console:

```
bool _CreateControl(HWND parent)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wx = {0};
    wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wx.lpfnWndProc = HandleMessageSetup;        // function which will handle messages
    wx.hInstance = _GetInstance(self);
    wx.lpszClassName = this->wndClassName;

    if (RegisterClassEx(&wx)) 
    {
        this->Window = CreateWindowExW(0,
            this->wndClassName,
            L"dummy_name",
            WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0, 0,     // make it a child
            parent,                   // parent here is console window
            NULL, _GetInstance(this), this);
        
        SetFocus(this->Window);       // give it a focus

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Note**: instance of this window is being created in another thread.

Although I give a focus to this window to receive input, right mouse button still produces events for the console and produces context menu.

Right now I'm processing RAWMOUSEINPUT and get WM_INPUT messages to my window. This is done because I needed somewhat close to `GetMouseRelative()` in DirectInput to make a rotating camera.

Console window serves for me as a graphics output.

Is there any way to disable parent window input processing? Or what can cause such behaviour, as input from mouse is being processed by two windows?

Comment: @pmg I don't really know how to make this, as I'm processing events in child window, that receives focus. Because I can't directly catch anything from console as it is in a separate process

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD. CMD is a console program like your's for operating the computer. `SetConsoleMode` *ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT - If the mouse pointer is within the borders of the console window and the window has the keyboard focus, mouse events generated by mouse movement and button presses are placed in the input buffer. These events are discarded by ReadFile or ReadConsole, even when this mode is enabled.*

Comment: @Noodles my window doesn't have this flag, but context menu is showing anyways

Comment: Well that is the problem, you have to set the flag.

Comment: @Noodles it doesn't care much

Comment: You are doing it wrong. [There is a better way to read mouse input from a console window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events).

Comment: @CodyGray nope, not wrong, RawInput is needed, because I do shooter-like camera, if I use WM_MOUSEMOVE then, if my cursor reaches border it will stop. But I can use a part of ReadConsoleInput to ignore a WM_CONTEXTMENU

Comment: Nowhere did I suggest to use WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Comment: This comment thread is being discussed [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384720/215552).

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the right mouse button of the console by customizing mouse input messages to achieve this goal.

It should be noted that,to add `ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS`(Enabling or disabling extension flags is necessary).

This is not added in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) sample, only after adding can the mouse message be processed.

```
fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;
```

In addition, if you want to disable the title bar of the console, you can refer to the following code.

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
LONG Style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, Style &~ WS_CAPTION);
```

Answer (score -2):

You would have to hook the `SetFocus` function, or otherwise specify that `WM_KILLFOCUS` should not apply to the command prompt window you're using.

> The SetFocus function sends a WM_KILLFOCUS message to the window that loses the keyboard focus and a WM_SETFOCUS message to the window that receives the keyboard focus. It also activates either the window that receives the focus or the parent of the window that receives the focus.
>
> If a window is active but does not have the focus, any key pressed will produce the WM_SYSCHAR, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, or WM_SYSKEYUP message. If the VK_MENU key is also pressed, the *lParam* parameter of the message will have bit 30 set. Otherwise, the messages produced do not have this bit set.
> By using the AttachThreadInput function, a thread can attach its input processing to another thread. This allows a thread to call SetFocus to set the keyboard focus to a window attached to another thread's message queue.

[Excerpt from SetFocus at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus)

Comment: Problem is: I don't know what's cmd thread or mine, so thread input is not going to work. I did a `SetFocus` on WM_KILLFOCUS, but it only processes keyboard messages, so I need to somehow disable mouse messages from working in CMD

Comment: Even though it's beyond the scope of this question, you can use the [`GetCurrentThreadId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadid) function that WinAPI provides in processthreadsapi.h to get the current thread ID. I've no idea whether or not that could help with what you're doing.

Comment: Hooking functions is not a good way to implement features. Either the console window has this feature, or it doesn't.

Comment: @immibis I do agree with your remark on that hooking functions is "not a good way to implement features". That does not however, touch the subject whatsoever.

Comment: @CodyGray if a handle to the program in question is passed instead of the next handle, it should redirect to the same window according to the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Especially hooking functions *in other processes* is a terrible idea.

Comment: @immibis That may have some problems regarding platform specific dependencies, yes. It's still a viable solution, even though it's "hacky".

Comment: Especially when the other process runs with administrative privileges (IIRC) and yours does not.

Comment: @immibis You can always ask for privileges, and a properly handled case would ask for privileges if the current ones are not sufficient when the use case necessitates them.

Comment: @shaks Getting mouse input to a console window is not a good reason to ask for elevated privileges.

Comment: @immibis Getting mouse input to a console window does not require elevating privileges.

Comment: @shaks because you don't do it by injecting code into the console window process.

Comment: @immibis You can do most things by injecting code to a process. That would however probably require elevating privileges, depending on context and method.

Comment: Which is why a sane programmer would not inject code into the console window process in order to be able to get mouse input in a console window.